# Why does Eclipse not work with Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I downloaded the entire SDK file with eclipse and all that, extracted the main file to my desktop, but when I try to open Eclipse from the folder, it gives me this convoluted list of errors. Including "Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment', Could not find java.dlll, Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment, and then it gives me a list of things I don't understand in a window. SDK:

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download
```

Could this be related at all to me using JCreator for my main IDE and I have the JCreator JDK and stuff? I didn't associate them with each other, but could just having a different JDK on your computer mess everything up?

Comment: Did u install JDK on your machine  ?

Comment: Ya I have the 7u45 one from oradocs for Windows x86

Comment: Do you have your Java home in your Environment Variables?  I am assuming you're using Windows 7/8.

Comment: Is it also the 32-bit Eclipse? You have to match the JRE/JDK and Eclipse when it comes to 32/64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the PATH permanently to include JDK's "bin" directory via "Control Panel" ⇒ "System"⇒ (Vista/7/8) "Advanced system settings" ⇒ Switch to "Advanced" tab ⇒ "Environment variables" ⇒ Under "System Variables" (for all users) ⇒ Select variable "PATH" ⇒ Choose "Edit" (for modifying an existing variable) ⇒ In "Value", INSERT your JDK's "bin" directory (e.g., "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_{xx}\bin"), followed by a semi-colon ';', above all the existing PATH entries.